# Multiple Page Check Box Handling

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, cgi

In GMail, the mails are listed. When we we have lots of mails (ex:50), we can select and go to next page, select some more mail, and come back to page 1. But whatever mails the user checked will still be checked.

I just want to implement the same operation. How would I do that?

Thanks,
Krish

**Note**: I don't want to use AJAX. I'd rather use Javascript, CGI, PERL, etc.

Comment: AJAX is Javascript. The normal way of using AJAX is to make a call to an external program (in your case written in Perl) and do something in Javascript (calculations, changes to the DOM) with the result. AJAX is Javascript.

Comment: I mean that i don't want to call any external Program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleValue(this)">` and in handler check the value and store it in array.
2. JQuery

```js
$('input[type=checkbox].mail').click(
    function()
    {
        if (this.checked) $(this).addClass('checked');
        else $(this).removeClass('checked');
    }
);
$('input[type=checkbox].mail.checked').each(function_here);
```

Can have some typos in the second one...

PS: don't know why, but the code above is not being formatted (

Answer (score 2):

Simple in theory.  Just store the ids of checked mail in a JavaScript variable and/or cookie, and let them access (via AJAX) as many checkbox lists as they want, before submitting.

Comment: i dont want use AJAX 

 NEED USE CGI , PERL

Answer (score 0):

After every time a user selects an email, add the message id to some array in a cookie (you probably want to preform this on-the-fly, with AJAX).

When you load a page with mail, check if the message id has been already checked, and if so, change the default state to checked.

Comment: NO AJAX. I can use CGI , PERL , JAVASCRIPT , HTML Templete

Answer (score 0):

I Just found the way of doing this using Java Script( no external Program ) and URL Parameters , onclick events , onload events , location.href, using global variable ,read form